# Where can I find a scatter plot of welfare spending vs. immigrant rate?

Tags: economy, immigration, social-welfare

Where can I find a scatter plot of welfare spending (per capita, % of spending, or % of GDP) vs. immigrant rate (per capita, or % of population)? By state or by country would be fine. I tried to search, but came up empty:

[welfare spending vs immigrant rate scatter plot](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=imgo%3A1&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=yJpSW_SHJMixggf5maXIDA&q=welfare+spending+vs+immigrant+rate+scatter+plot&oq=welfare+spending+vs+immigrant+rate+scatter+plot&gs_l=img.3...37312.37312.0.38233.1.1.0.0.0.0.85.85.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.wWQFS2g8aQE#imgrc=_)

Comment: Why should anyone else care about this plot, particularly here?  What question [are you actually trying to answer with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: There is lots of software that can make any graph you want from any data you provide.

Comment: I want to see if there is any correlation. This is definitely on topic.

Comment: Asking about the relationship between welfare spending and immigration might be on topic (if it's not formulated too broadly). Asking about data to proof your point isn't. You might try [opendata.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) (I'm not familiar with them, but their help page sounds fitting).

Comment: Both statistics are easily available separately. If you want to compare them, put them in an Xcel spreadsheet and make your own scatterplot.

Comment: The racist downvoters don't want the truth to get out.

Comment: @Chloe, The downvotes (I assume) are because asking to find a scatter plot is of no value to most people.  A better question would be is there a correlation between welfare spending and immigrant rate (I don't know what that last term means.)  Perhaps you want to know how much does an average immigrant receive in welfare payments?  Or how much money does an immigrant receive when coming to the country?  Unless I'm missing the real point of your query.  And if I am then that shows you the question needs improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more complete answer which includes all types of welfare, not just unemployment benefits, and 50 data points, not just a dozen. It also has a trend line which shows no correlation.

[image: welfare spending vs. immigrant rate by state]

[Source Data ODS Sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/107oZoiExK7e4NbBvdLQmxH3iApu2tUCn/view?usp=sharing)

https://www.usgovernmentspending.com/state_spending_rank_2016p40a
https://cis.org/sites/cis.org/files/immigrant-profile_0.pdf, https://cis.org/Report/Immigrants-United-States
http://www.pewhispanic.org/interactives/unauthorized-immigrants/map/population-share/ (not used)

Comment: I guess you were looking for US-only, but you didn't specify that in your question in any way.

Comment: @Fizz Wasn't looking for US-only. "By state or by country would be fine."

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking into the "welfare magnet hypothesis", there are plenty of papers, e.g. [this](https://wol.iza.org/uploads/articles/37/pdfs/welfare-magnet-hypothesis-and-welfare-take-up-of-migrants.pdf) has a reasonably close plot what you ask for:

[image]

with the commentary

> An essentially null effect also emerges when looking at spending on unemployment benefits
>   as a percentage of GDP [7]. Data from 19 EU countries for the period 1998–2008 show a
>   small positive association between spending on unemployment benefits and immigration
>   flows for immigrants from non-EU origins (see Figure 2). But the effect was essentially zero
>   after taking into account that immigration itself affects the level of public expenditure.
>   Factors such as income, unemployment rates, and the presence of previous immigrants in
>   the receiving country were instead the major determinants of immigration flows.
>
> - [7] Giulietti, C., M. Guzi, M. Kahanec, and K. F. Zimmermann. “Unemployment benefits and
>     immigration: Evidence from the EU.” International Journal of Manpower 34:1 (2013): 24–38.
>     Online at: http://www.emeraldinsight.com/journals.htm?articleid=17085869&show=abstract